# Cron - Every sunday, except if it's the first day of the month

Tags: cron

I have three levels of backups:

- Full - that is run on the first day of the month
- Weekly - run every sunday
- Daily - run every other day.

I though of setting them up this way:

```
0 0 1 * * - full
0 0 2-31 * 1 - weekly
0 0 2-31 * 0,2,3,4,5,6 - daily
```

But it turns out setting the day of month and day of week is an either-or relation, not and, so the weekly and daily backups actually run on EVERY day, instead of running on every monday except the first day of month, and every other day than monday except the first day of month.

Can cron be set up the way I want to set it up?

Thanks,

Comment: You could check if today is the first of the month as part of the command you're running, something like `[[ $(date '+\%d') != '01' ]] && backupcommand`. (Escaping `%` is important!) Notice that this requires your `SHELL` to be Bash. Alternatively, you could use `[ ! "$(date '+\%d')" = '01' ] && backupcommand`.

Comment: @BenjaminW., maybe it is better to compare numbers with `-ne` not with `!=`

Comment: I wound up using the workaround suggested by @BenjaminW.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Then I have to watch out for interpretation as octal because of the leading zero. Alternatively, the formatting directive could be `%-d` to drop the leading zero, and then you could use `-ne`, but I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: @BenjaminW., you compare `01` which in binary, octal, decimal is the same :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov Sure – but if I switch to `09`, it'll break. I'm saying that using `-ne` and the output of `date +%d` is not robust.

Comment: @BenjaminW., days of week are the same in octal, decimal, hex :) (and in any numeric system `-gt` 6 )

Comment: @RomeoNinov But `%d` is the day of the month, zero padded. Feel free to post an answer using `-gt` if you feel so strongly about it.